# How is `flutter_localizations` imported into Flutter project when it's not available on pub.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am wondering how this is possible. The `flutter_localizations` package is not on pub.dev which makes me think that it's part of `flutter` package? But if so, how come I have to import it like `package:flutter_localizatoins/flutter_localizations.dart` into a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

> TLDR: In your `pubspec.yaml`, is not added like a regular dependency

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

It works the same way as flutter(it comes bundled with the sdk itself) which you also import its packages like:
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart'`

Answer (score -1):

To use localized messages configured with `intl` package (this is the way from official docs) add this import:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
```

It will be generated during build.
Use messages this way:

```
final localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
print(localizations.hello);
```

For more details see docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization).